# State size and checkpoint size in Flink SQL streaming query with TVF aggregation keeps growing

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

We are using Flink SQL to define a stream processing pipeline that computes a SUM aggregation over a fixed window of 5 minutes. The query looks something like this:

```
 INSERT INTO BigTableTable
 SELECT CONCAT_WS('#', user, attribute, bucket) as rowkey, ROW(sum_attribute), cell_timestamp
 FROM (
   SELECT
     user,
     attribute,
     DATE_FORMAT(window_end, 'yyyy-MM-dd:HH') AS bucket,
     SUM(attribute_to_sum) AS sum_attribute,
     window_end as cell_timestamp
   FROM TABLE(TUMBLE(TABLE inputTable, DESCRIPTOR(event_time), INTERVAL '5' MINUTES))
   GROUP BY user, attribute, window_start, window_end)
```

We are using `EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend` with incremental checkpointing and also unaligned checkpoints.

We enabled some native rocksdb metrics to monitor the live state size, and also monitor the checkpoint size and we are seeing that these keep growing over time. This is a bit counterintuitive since our understanding is that the window state will be wipped out once the window closes and fires.

We have also enabled the state ttl in table api with:  `tableEnvironment.getConfig.setIdleStateRetention(Duration.ofMinutes(10))`, but this doesn't seem to change anything.

Here are the two graphs for state size and checkpoint size:
[State Live Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khZcd.png)
[Checkpoint Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB99Q.png)

Why does the state keep growing and is not bounded by the number of keys in the inout stream?

Update:

Here's the same two metrics with aligned checkpoints [Checkpoint Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhS8j.png) [State Live Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTXjX.png)

Comment: What version of Flink is this? Have you tried aligned checkpoints?

Comment: We are using version `1.15.0`. I can try with aligned checkpoints and monitor the same metrics and report back.

Comment: 1.15.0 hasn't been released yet -- is this with rc4? Looking forward to comparing the results between unaligned and aligned.

Comment: Here are the graphs for the same two metrics but with aligned checkpoints. It seems like both the state size and the checkpoint size keep increasing. (I update the initial question with the metrics for aligned checkpoints)

Comment: Have you tried 1.14.4?

Comment: Hello. I did try 1.14.4 and even though the jobs showed similar state and checkpoint size metrics, where it was increasing, these metrics were way lower than the ones with 1.15.0. One thing we did realize is that when the job is up to date with the backlog, thse metrics go down abruptly. Having seen this, my understanding is that once we have the source consuming events at a steady rate, fewer windows will be open at the same time (compared to when it is trying to catch up or consume the backlog), which means that less state is going to be needed. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Is there any known regression in performance with 1.15.0?

Comment: I'm not aware of any performance regression in 1.15.0, but it also hasn't been officially released yet (the binaries are there, but the announcement is not yet out)